# Find an uncommon length in a list

Tags: python

I need to find out which lines aren't the same length, but the code I have is saying all lines that aren't like the most common word is an uncommon length even though they are indeed the same length. Here is my code.

```
import collections


fle= ['hello', 'hello', 'hello','justi', 'hello','no', 'hello', 'no']


count= sum(1 for n in fle)
print count

most_common_length = collections.Counter(fle).most_common(1)[0][0]
print most_common_length

mcl = len(most_common_length)

uncommon = [n for n, v in enumerate(fle) if v != most_common_length]
print uncommon
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line

```
uncommon = [n for n, v in enumerate(fle) if v != most_common_length]
```

You are effectively comparing each word in the array against 'hello' rather than comparing the length of the word with the length of the most common word. it should be

```
uncommon = [n for n, v in enumerate(fle) if len(v) != mcl]
```

Then the output will be [5,7] which tells you that the words at index 5 and 7 have uncommon length.

Comment: I tried this and it worked, but now i changed it  a little, now no words are alike, but some still have the same length of 5 letters, when i do this it says that no is the most common length

Comment: If it works, the standard procedure here at stackoverflow is to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
most_common_length = collections.Counter(fle).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

You're a victim of misleading variable names. `most_common_length` isn't that at all. It's actually the most common *word*. Notice that there's no call to `len` in the `collections.Counter` line. It's not counting word lengths, it's counting words.

It's important to fix this line and count lengths. Don't try to work around the bad search by computing the length of the result, which is what you're doing with `mcl`. The length of the most common word is not necessarily the same as the most common length.

```
uncommon = [n for n, v in enumerate(fle) if v != most_common_length]
```

Once you fix that you'll find another problem. The comparison at the end compares `v` against the most common length. It should be `len(v)`. You want to compare lengths with lengths.

Answer (score 0):

**Get the average length and the print the ones below the average:**

```
fle = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello','justi', 'hello','no', 'hello', 'no']
avg = sum([len(x) for x in fle])/len((fle))
print "The following items appear to have an uncommon length: {}".format(', '.join([x for x in fle if len(x) < avg]))
```

**Output:**

```
The following items appear to have an uncommon length: no, no
```

Answer (score 0):

You must compare the lengths not values in

```
uncommon = [n for n, v in enumerate(fle) if v != most_common_length]
```

Also you can use filter

```
uncommon = list( filter( lambda x:len(x) != most_common_length, fle) )
```